# Document.createTextNode pass integer?

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to pass count(integer) to "NbOfTxs", which is supposed to be a number in the xml document.

I've tried dereferencing and parsing the integer but I can't seem to solve it.

```
            Element NbOfTxs = document.createElement("NbOfTxs");
            NbOfTxs.appendChild(document.createTextNode(count);
            GrpHdr.appendChild(NbOfTxs);
```

If you were to pass count here, how would you do that to not get an error? I'm new to working with XML documents in java

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace

Comment: Show us the XML Schema and/or DTD.

Comment: @jeanr it's not that kind of error, it wont compile with an integer in there, if you understand what i mean, i can't run the program with an integer as a parameter to document.createTextNode(>>trying to pass integer<<)